# R: Determine if all sets in a list appear in a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, search, contains

I need to figure out if sets of item ID's are found within a data frame.
If I'm only looking for a single set of ID's, the below code works just fine:

```
set <- c( id1, id2, etc...)
all(subSets %in% df[,rangeOfColumns])
```

However, if the set is a list of various things I want to check, this code doesn't work as expected and I am unsure how to get this functionality.

Example of what I'm aiming for:

```
set <- list()
set[[1]] <- c(1, 2)
set[[2]] <- c(2, 3)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1:4),c(2:5)))

all(set %in% df)
#Returns TRUE
```

Comment: What do you mean by "appear in a data frame"? Do you mean `set[[1]]` is exactly a row in `df` (which is true)? Or you you mean `set[[1]]` is a subset of `df$V1` or a subset of `df$V2` (which is also true)?

Comment: Sorry.  I meant if any of the sets appear in any row, it's true.  So if if all the sets are found in any of the rows, the whole thing is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check each row against each set and return TRUE if any row matches. Then if there is a match for each set, then the whole result is TRUE.

```
all(sapply(set, function(s) 
    any(apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x==s)))))
```

Comment: Yup. Pretty sure this was what I was after.  I was on the right track, but getting the exact syntax with a nested apply... ugh...  Spacing it out like you did helps to break it up visually though; I'll need to start doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be easy to understand but it does the job. Data frames are organized by column, so doing things by row isn't always straightforward.

```
# Your setup had some unnecessary complications. Here it is again 
# more simply:
set <- list(1:2, 2:3)
d_f <- data.frame(1:4, 2:5) # df is already a function name so best not to use it again.

all(
  sapply(seq_along(set), 
         function(i) any(
           sapply(
             lapply(1:nrow(d_f), function(j) set[[i]] == d_f[j,]), 
             all) # Does each element of set[[i]] equal the elements in df[j]?
           )
         ) # Does it happen in any row of df?
  ) # It is true for all elements of set?
```

EDIT: to address the question in the comment *Well, if it's not straight-forward, why not work with a transposed version of the df to make things easier?*

Because a data frame is a list, not a matrix.

Doing matrix things (like transpose with `t` or using `apply`) ruin (often without any warning to the user) what a data frame is supposed to be, which is a list of vectors of the same length.

When you use `t` or `apply` on a data frame, the first thing to happen is `as.matrix` gets applied to it. And if your data frame has a date, character, or factor variable, then the whole thing is coerced to "character", and it doesn't tell you this happens.

An answer for your specific problem can be crafted using `apply` (as someone did) and/or `t`, but it's going to be a bit fragile unless one is completely sure of the classes of the variables in the data frame.

Comment: Well, if it's not straight-forward, why not work with a transposed version of the df to make things easier?